# Vuetify navigation drawer inside v-card

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I put a navigation drawer inside a v-card and not whole app??

I have the global navigation drawer running fine, but I need setup other temporary navigation drawer inside a v-card.

```
<v-card @contextmenu="getCursor">
    <v-navigation-drawer temporary absolute v-model="drawer">
      <p>Test navigation drawer</p>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar dark class="secondary" fluid dense>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Calendar week</v-toolbar-title>
      ...
      ...
    </v-toolbar>
  ...
  ...
</v-card>
```

this shown the navigation-drawer fine but always is visible to the left of the v-card.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<v-navigation-drawer temporary fixed v-model="drawer">
```

Answer (score 0):

here a complete example how a menu incl. drawer looks in a v-card in vue 3 with

```
<template>
<v-layout>
    <v-container align="left">
        <v-card max-height="300" min-height="200">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-layout>
                    <!-- <v-system-bar color="deep-purple darken-3"></v-system-bar> -->

                    <v-app-bar  
                        color="primary"
                    >
                        <v-app-bar-nav-icon variant="text" @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
                        <v-toolbar-title> {{ drawer }}</v-toolbar-title>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn variant="text" icon="mdi-magnify"></v-btn>
                        <v-btn variant="text" icon="mdi-dots-vertical"></v-btn>
                    </v-app-bar>

                    <v-navigation-drawer
                        :width="100"                   
                        v-model="drawer"
                    >
                        <v-list
                        :items="items"
                        ></v-list>
                    </v-navigation-drawer>

                    <v-main>
                        <v-card min-height="150">
                            <v-card-text>
                                    This is a test text. <br> Your content could be here.
                            </v-card-text>
                        </v-card>
                        
                    </v-main>
                </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>      
        
    </v-container>
</v-layout>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

let drawer = ref(false)

let items = [
    { 
        title: 'Products', 
        value: 'prod'
    },
    {
        title: 'About', 
        value: 'about'
    },
    {
        title: '...', 
        value: 'etc'
    },
]
</script>

<style>

</style>
```